# How to Deploy CodeIgniter/Laravel Apps

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

I need to know which are my options when deploying codeigniter/laravel apps.

I develop locally all the time at my home and when i go to work i need some quick way to push all the changes to the server.

Application code needs to be updated, database schemas need to be migrated, and application servers must be restarted.

I do all of this manually wasting a lot of time and i need some automated way kinda like capistrano in Rails environment.

What are my options here ??

**Update:**
I got my own server machine, and everything needs to work on an intranet environment without internet connection.

Comment: I'm curious to see what anyone comes up with on this. I'm sort of in the same boat. We use git, but our server environment is not conducive to "automatic" deployment, either. DB migration has always been a pain. I tend to just generate a sql file with the changes and run that on the prod db.

Comment: Have you looked at using the built-in CodeIgniter database migration class?  If I'm reading this right, you can just use git to deploy your application code and then run the migration process:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/migration.html

Comment: Excellent question. I'm just pondering this problem myself. Hope we get more responses.

Answer (score 7):

I've used the following:

1. Salt - http://www.saltstack.org/

   Worked well, a bit fiddly to setup.  Super fast deployment.  Lots of control.  Less learning overhead that Puppet & Chef, has some level of native MySQL tools.
2. GitHub

   Requires a internet connection to/from your machine - one where, at some level, the end point as write permissions to interactive scripts....  Works, but makes me nervous.  Pulls are better than pushes, and it's better than most other solutions.
3. Custom shell scripting

   Yeah - this is the most common, just tar up the entire CI dir once it's been validated on staging and push out using Salt...
4. Scalextreme

   We've been looking at this for a few months - the interface is from the 1990's, but it's got really nice functionality, including system-independent script library that you can target at any machine.
5. Turnkey Linux

   The hammer - this will migrate an entire system image from a desktop to EC2 is something like 5 minutes.  Works great and you can also move stuff between VM systems.  In the end, I think that updating AMI's on EC2 is so easy that this might be one of the answers...

Nothing has truly been satisfactory and DB schema changes are a huge pain.  So much so that for client configs, we're moving from MySQL to Cassandra, which is basically schemaless.  CI installer is interesting, but I'm not sure how it handles updates.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across [this CodeIgniter Installer](https://github.com/mikecrittenden/codeigniter-installer) on GitHub. I've played around with it a few times and it works like a charm for me.

It's as simple as putting it in your root directory (alongside your system folder), generating a MySQL dump, and editing a few files. [Full instructions are here](https://github.com/mikecrittenden/codeigniter-installer/blob/master/README.md)

I hope it works for you as well as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Laravel Installer](https://github.com/RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller) on Github which might be useful. (First I came across this question after searching for Laravel installer in Google, then searched Github for Laravel Installer)